# call helper methods on a specific view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I had to overload the `link_to` method in a helper method I wrote. But I only wanted it to be overridden for some specific views (basically all the mailer views). But its being called on all the link_to on all the views and so breaking a lot of things. Is there a way to make my version of link_to to be called only in views that I want and not all of them .

I have used `helper HelperModuleName` in the controllers for the mailers but it's still being called everywhere

Comment: Where have you defined HelperModuleName?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to implement a helper module within app/helpers that defines a new method which uses link_to helper. This method you can use within your mailer views only.

```
module LinkToExtensionHelper
  def mailer_link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
    # edit or change name, options, or html_options here like you want
    link = link_to(name, options, html_options, &block)
    if block_given?
      yield(link)
    else
      link
    end
  end
end
```

This way you don't have to overload/override the original link_to helper and so you keep the original behavior of link_to.